# Using SUM() with LIMIT sums all rows in the table ignoring the limit

Tags: sqlite, sum, limit

The following two SQLite queries return the same result, the LIMIT is ignored. Is there a workaround?

SQL

```
select count(*),sum(close) from history where symbol=494 limit 1;  
select count(*),sum(close) from history where symbol=494;
```

OUTPUT

```
#   Count(*)    Sum(close)
1.  501         97836.04
2.  501         97836.04
```

Comment: Your query returns only 1 row so LIMIT 1 does nothing.

Comment: You're trying to sum a column of a single row? And limit without order by will return arbitrary rows of the result set so isn't much use...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to apply a LIMIT and count afterwards, you should make an embedded query:

```
select count(*),sum(close) 
from 
(
  select close from history where symbol=494 limit 1
) t
```

But this query hardly make sense.

Answer (score 0):

**count()** and **sum()** are [**aggregate**](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) functions, they work on a **GROUP** of rows, returning a sigle value (row) per group.If no GROUP BY clause is present then the default group is ALL rows.

So using LIMIT makes no sense in that context

If, as an example, your history table had a date column and you grouped according to a date then you could get multiple rows if there were multiple groups and the LIMIT may then make some sense.

Consider the following example SQL and results :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS history;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS history (symbol INTEGER,close REAL, date TEXT);
INSERT INTO history VALUES 
    (494,2103.04,'20019-01-01'),(494,512.45,'2019-02-01'),(494,765.34,'2019-03-01'),
    (494,2103.04,'20019-01-02'),(494,512.45,'2019-02-02'),(494,765.34,'2019-03-02'), 
    (495,2103.04,'20019-01-01'),(495,512.45,'2019-02-01'),(495,765.34,'2019-03-01')
; 

/* Excluded by selects due to WHERE symbol=494 */
select count(*),sum(close) from history where symbol=494; 
/* multiple counts and sums due to grouping by year and month */
select count(*),sum(close) from history where symbol=494 GROUP BY strftime('%Y%m',date); 
/* IN this case LIMIT in association with ORDER returns the lowest sum of all the groups (year and month) */
select count(*),sum(close) from history as h where symbol=494  GROUP BY strftime('%Y%m',date) ORDER BY sum(close) ASC  LIMIT 1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS history; /* cleanup test */
```

**First Query**

[image]

**Second Query** (multiple groups)

[image]

**Third Query** (lowest sum of the groups)

[image]